# Drive 3 1.2V LEDs with same current with input ranging from 2.5V to 5V

Tags: led, current-source, led-driver, constant-current

[image: What I need]

I don't need to control the LEDs in any way, I just need them to turn on when connected to a power source.
I have considered putting all the LEDs in series, but then I would need at least 3.6V.
I am almost settling for a voltage regulator for each LED:
[image: Possible solution]

The problem with this solution is that the efficiency is pretty low, and since this circuit can be connected to a battery, it is something I need to keep in mind.

It needs to be a very small circuit as well. A small circuit for each LED is preferrable to a single bigger circuit for all 3 LEDs.

I appreciate any suggestions or leads.

EDIT:

The efficiency requirements are not that tight. Around 80% efficiency is enough. I have a background in electronics but no experience in constant current circuits. The LEDs are infrared, hence the 1.2V and 50ma.

Comment: There is little problem delivering a low constant current with a rail of at least 2.5 V and LEDs needing 1.2 V using a pair of BJTs. But at 50 mA, the Vbe is higher and it becomes slightly trickier. Still easily done. But another BJT is likely required. What kinds of constant current circuits are you familiar with? Do you need this to be highly efficient? Or can you afford to waste some power in a linear circuit? You say maybe not. But I'd like more detail about it.

Comment: That LM317 would draw almost the same amount of power as an LED.

Comment: Why do you need 50mA of current for LEDs? Also, where did you get 1.2V LEDs? I don't remember ever seeing any, except for infra-red.

Comment: @EdinFifić Some IR LEDs at 50 mA will be about 1.2 V. Not all of them, though. (I've used such as a vehicle-mounted traffic light control for emergency vehicles, many years ago.) Good question, though!

Comment: The LM317 is inappropriate here, it requires about 4.25V (3V for the regulator and 1.25V Vref across the resistor)  in addition to the 1.2V LED voltage, so 5.45V, to regulate properly.

Comment: @user38979  If you have found my answer useful, you should also hit the up arrow on it to upvote it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circuit has some rare restraints. If I were doing it for myself, my simplest solution would be one of those cheap synchronous buck converter modules, like this one (taken from https://circuit.rocks/product:2314):
[image]  
It uses an MP2307 IC ([datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MP2307_r1.9.pdf)), but it doesn't work at the low voltage you have indicated. It would have been a simple matter of setting the voltage, placing LEDs in parallel, with a low value resistor in series with each separately.

For your purpose, you would need a specific IC, like MPQ2171, for example. Below is a cutout from its [datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MPQ2171/document_id/5017/):
[image]

You would add the 3 diodes in parallel with each other, but each with its own series resistor, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6eyCr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current would not be very stable, because the change in an LEDs forward voltage drop would cause a change in its current, but this might be enough for your purpose. It is fairly simple and efficient, with resistors wasting only about 1/13 of the 1.3V, or about 7.7% (more than 93% efficiency). 
The buck converter's efficiency should be more than 80%, and you should use a larger value inductor than what's indicated in the schematic: for 1A output current they recommend 0.68uH, but since your current is about 7 times lower, you should use 3.3-4.7uH.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCSKi9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit is just to illustrate a way to use PWM and an inductor to drive an LED (represented by D3 and D4), regulated to about 60 mA by reading current through the LEDs using 10 ohm source resistor R2. A standard 555 timer needs at least 5V power, but a LMC555 (CMOS) will work as low as 2 volts. A much simpler implementation might be made using a comparator or a small microcontroller. Here are some waveforms:

[image: Voltages]

[image: LED current]

I designed another circuit using a micropower comparator that runs a PWM current through a simulated 1.5V IR LED, and it seems to work well from 2.5V to 12V. LED current is determined by the sampling resistor R1 and the forward voltage of an NPN B-E junction, so 10 ohms provides about 70 mA. The comparator was added primarily to get a sharp gate drive voltage to reduce power in the MOSFET, but it will work without it. PWM frequency is about 5 kHz at 2.5V, and 50 kHz at 12V.

[image: Current Regulated LED PWM]

Here is the simplified circuit:

[image: Simpler circuit]